# Use dplyr to change an R dataframe from second row across multiple columns

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a large dataframe similar to the toy dataset created below

```
df<-data.frame("ID"=c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
'A_Frequency'=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), 'A_Axis'=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5))
```

The dataframe consists of an ID column and a two columns A_Frequency and A_Axis. 
I have created a column called A_Slope and filled it using the following for loop

```
id1<-unique(df$ID)###########Create list of unique IDs to subset the dataframe
```

In this loop we calculate A_Slope value such that the values are calculated subsetting the dataframe df by unique id and then, the values are calculated from the second row to the last row, ignoring the first row in all cases

```
for( j in id1){
for( i in 2:nrow(df[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j],])){
df$A_Slope[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j]][i]=10*log(2, 
10)*log((df$A_Axis[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j]][i])/

(df$A_Axis[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j]][i-1]), base = 
10)/log((df$A_Frequency[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j]] 
[i])/(df$A_Frequency[df$ID==df$ID[df$ID%in%j]][i-1]),base = 10 )}}
```

This works well for the toy set. I have a large dataframe with multiple columns. is it possible to use dplyr to do the same using mutate.

Expected Output

```
        ID A_Frequency A_Axis     A_Slope
     1   A           1      1          NA
     2   A           2      2 3.010299957
     3   A           3      3 3.010299957
     4   A           4      4 3.010299957
     5   A           5      5 3.010299957
     6   B           1      1          NA
     7   B           2      2 3.010299957
     8   B           3      3 3.010299957
     9   B           4      4 3.010299957
     10  B           5      5 3.010299957
```

Note : the two NA values in A_Slope column can be zero also- not necessrily NA

Comment: Can you update your post with expected output for the toy example ?

Comment: Have made the edit as requested

Comment: Can you please *explain* what the rules are for calculating `A_Slope`? I struggle to de-convolute your code, which unfortunately is not very readable due the lack of any indentation/whitespace/formatting.

Comment: The term slope is just a name- not to be confused with dy/df in calculus. Will add few comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I have translated your code correctly.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(A_Slope = 10 * log10(2) * log10(A_Axis/lag(A_Axis))/
                                    log10(A_Frequency/lag(A_Frequency)))


#  ID    A_Frequency A_Axis A_Slope
#  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 A               1      1    NA   
# 2 A               2      2    3.01
# 3 A               3      3    3.01
# 4 A               4      4    3.01
# 5 A               5      5    3.01
# 6 B               1      1    NA   
# 7 B               2      2    3.01
# 8 B               3      3    3.01
# 9 B               4      4    3.01
#10 B               5      5    3.01
```

Some pointers to understand the code

- `log(x, 10)` replaced with `log10(x)`
- to get previous value (`i - 1`) we use `lag` here.

Comment: Looks correct. I need one clarification. Will dplyr ignore the first row by default as NA

Comment: @marciaakshayaLeo No..It will not but as we are using `lag` here, `lag` gives default first value as `NA` and any multiplication/division (which we are doing here) done with `NA` would result into `NA` hence for first row of every `ID` it gives output as `NA`.